# Hiding menu element by permission using AngularJS and Web API

Tags: angularjs, html, asp.net-web-api

I have implemented roles based authorization in my Web API RESTfull service using OWIN.

What would be the best way to hide menu items or buttons based on the role that the user has? I want to hide the items that the user has no access to.

**UPDATED**

I want to know what the best practice is for my controller.

This is an example of what I want, but I don't think it is the right way to do it. Second, the routing fails because it cannot distinguish between the two actions.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "SomeRole")]
public class FooController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
         return "Hello world - you are authorized";
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("hasaccess")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public bool HasAccess()
    {
         return User.IsInRole("SomeRole");
    }
}
```

> http://localhost:8080/api/foo/ --> calls HelloWorld()
>
> http://localhost:8080/api/foo/hasaccess --> calls HasAccess()

Answer (score 1):

You could use ng-if directive. It will render this `div` only if hasRole function returns true.

```
<div ng-if="hasRole('admin')"> 
                  Admin menu item
</div>
```

And then in controller have a function

```
$scope.hasRole = function(role){
    //check if user has needed Role
    //return true or false
}
```

Comment: And how about the ApiController? Any thoughts on how to do that?

Comment: You mean how to store user roles in front-end?